# how to modify a javascript file that adds function to $.fn to use requirejs?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have a javascript file that has

```
$.fn.comments = function (method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' doesn not exists in jQuery.comments');
        return null;
    }
};
```

I've seen intro requirejs tutorials to return functions from a module.

But this javascript adds function to $.fn , how do I change this file so that I can use requirejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy approach:

```
define(
  ['jQuery'],
  function ($) {
     $.fn.comments = .. /* do side effects as per the original */;
     return {
       /* ehh, others don't get a useful return,
          but we did our side-effect work upon jQuery (via $.fn) above */
     };
  });
```

One *could* also return something if this module has a value that could be used as something useful in a dependent module, although the biggest hook with a jQuery plugin is to *do a side-effect upon `$.fn`* so that said jQuery plugin can then be accessed as `$(..).plugin`.  So, then a dependent:

```
define(
  ['jQuery', 'jQuery_comments'], /* require comment module */
  function ($, _comments) {      /* but don't care about value */
      /* and use plugin anyway as it's already been registered
         through a side-effect on $.fn */
      return {
        doStuff: function (..) {
          $(..).comments(..);
        }
      };
  });
```

Alternatively, one could return `comments` (`function (method) { .. }`) from the dependency module and use `$.fn.comments = comments` in the dependent module, but I'd leave it like it is above as jQuery plugins *are* inherently side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Working under the assumption that this is not a plugin that you wrote/maintain, my recommendation would be to leave the plugin alone and use some of requirejs's configuration features to tell it how to work with your plugin.

Adding the following requirejs.config will tell requirejs how to handle your plugin.

```
requirejs.config({
    shim:{
        'jquery.comments': {               // module name
            deps: [ 'jquery' ],            // jquery dependency
            exports: 'jQuery.fn.comments'  // result of the module
        }
    }
});
```

Here's some more documentation on this feature: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim.

With this configuration if you eventually want to use a newer version of the plugin, you can just drop in the file and it should work, whereas if you make change to the file to make it model the requirejs pattern, you'll need to make those change again and again should you choose to upgrade the plugin later.  Both ways work, but I prefer this one as it is better for longer-term maintainability.